# Show element based on input being focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a piece of code a little more efficient. The concept is that when you focus the textarea, you are shown a paragraph tag that tells you the characters remaining. Currently i have:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Idea extends Component {
  state = {
    showCharactersRemaining: false
  };

  calculateRemaining() {
    return 15 - this.props.body.length;
  }

  onTextAreaFocus = () => {
    this.setState(state => {
      return { showCharactersRemaining: true };
    });
  };

  onBlur = () => {
    this.setState(state => {
      return { showCharactersRemaining: false };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { title, body } = this.props;
    const { showCharactersRemaining } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="idea">
        <input type="text" name="title" value={title} />
        <textarea
          rows="3"
          name="body"
          maxlength="15"
          value={body}
          onFocus={this.onTextAreaFocus}
          onBlur={this.onBlur}
        />
        {showCharactersRemaining && (
          <p>{this.calculateRemaining()} characters remaining.</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Idea;
```

Which works but also relies on having two methods attached to said textarea to make it work. Is there a smarter way in react of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

CSS can handle it for you, removing the necessity for state and either event handler. Run the snippet to see it work (I removed the logic for counting characters to keep this example simple)

```css
.charcount {
  display: none;
}

textarea:focus+.charcount {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="idea">
  <textarea rows="3" name="body" maxlength="15" value="foo"></textarea>
  <p class="charcount">XX characters remaining.</p>
</div>
```